# VB.NET and a 'login session'

Tags: vb.net

I am making a application in VB that uses MySQL as database. I have a `frmMain` and a form called `frmLogin`. When I login, the login form checks the database if the user entered the correct username and password. I want them to return to `frmMain` and pass the information (eg. id, login name and role) as a string (or something safer) in `frmMain` but I don't know whats the best way to do it.

Here is my code in `frmLogin` (I know about the sql injections):

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Dim loginResult As String

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextGebruikersNaam.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextGebruikersPass.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Voer uw gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord in om in te loggen. ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Foutmelding")
        TextGebruikersNaam.Focus()
    Else
        Dim newPass As String
        newPass = HashString.getSHA1Hash(TextGebruikersPass.Text)

        loginResult = SQLHook.Counter("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblgebruikers WHERE GebruikersNaam='" & TextGebruikersNaam.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "' AND GebruikersPass='" & newPass.Replace("'", "''") & "'")

        If loginResult = 1 Then
            ' Login is cewl, now set some strings and unload this form so user
            ' could continue on frmMain.
        Else
            MsgBox("De gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord is onjuist.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Foutmelding")
            TextGebruikersPass.Text = ""
            TextGebruikersPass.Focus()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there are safe way to set a (eg.) String with the username and a role (thats inside the database too as a 'GebruikersRole' row.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use session or application variables to keep your data accessible through our the application or you can create a class like Person info and assign those value to properties within that class and it'll be accessible throughout the application

EDIT: 
Create a class

CLASS PERSON

private _username as string

public shared property username as string
get
    return _username
end get
set(value of string)
    _username = value
end set

END CLASS

this will make the the login info available to the entire application just reference the person object.

Comment: That will be something like (eg. `Public Shared UserName As String`) in a Module?

Comment: Thank you @Valen. The example code is `    Private _name As String

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Private Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property`

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

In an easy way, you can set a Public variable to keep the login and the informations

```
Public Class frmLogin
Public Login as String
Public Informations as String

Login_Click
....
If loginResult = 1 Then
   Login = "xxx"
   Informations = "yyy"
   Me.Visible = False
   frmMain.ShowDialog()
Else ....
```

Now in frmMain, use frmLogin.Variable to get the values.

```
If frmLogin.Login = "xxxx" Then
   .....
```

I think that it's not the best way to do it, but it could be the enough depending on your needs.
cya