# Vb.net : Get Set properties with different forms

Tags: vb.net, properties

I have a class with get and set properties

```
Public Property username() As String
    Get
        Return _username
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _username = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I want to set the value in one form and get the same value in another form how do i do this?

Comment: VB.NET makes it easy to forget that .NET uses object-oriented programming techniques.  You can use Form1.username in Form2.  You can learn the proper style from any introductory book about .NET programming.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare that property on one form, so when you instantiate it you can set it before showing or while doing some other action:

```
Dim newForm As Form2 = new Form2()
newForm.UserName = "Alejandro"
newForm.Show()
```

This assumes that the property `UserName` was declared on `Form2` as public. It's perfectly possible to do the other way around, or even add that piece of data as a constructor parameter and keep the property private.

Comment: Basically I want to create a login session alternative. According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090556/vb-net-and-a-login-session I have made a separate class with multiple properties and I want this information accessible and changeable not just between two forms but throughout  the entire application